# Websocket : Unexpected response code: 302

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

When creating a websocket connection I am getting following exception:

```
VM74253:149 WebSocket connection to 'wss://HerokuAppName.herokuapp.com/connect2Deploy' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302
```

Spring boot Code for websocket:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new SocketHandler(), "/connect2Deploy");
    }
}
```

Sockethandler class only has session details because I only want session details to send server details to UI, there wont be any client to server communication.

```
@Component
public class SocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    public WebSocketSession sessions = null;

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        //the messages will be broadcasted to all users.
        sessions = session;
    }

    public WebSocketSession getSessions() {
        return sessions;
    }
}
```

But it always throws `error during websocket handshake`, am I missing something here?